# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: java, android

I try to run a new build that time i get a below error
**My error**

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.    :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

**My gradle file:**

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    test {
        keyAlias 'keystore'
        keyPassword 'vinoth'
        storeFile file('/root/AndroidStudioProjects/KeyStore/keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'vinoth'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.test
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.test
    }
}
productFlavors {
}}
```

My compile and build version are same
How to solve my problem. Help me anyone

**Edit code**
**My another gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}}task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

**Solution:**
I added picasa dependencie in my gradle file that is problem.
After i remove the dependencie it working.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33953133/2686502) maybe?

Comment: post your other gradle.build code

Comment: I updated my another gradle file

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 already i tried but not working

Comment: @VinothKumar post the entire stack trace of the error

Comment: Check my updated error now

Comment: @VinothKumar I dont think this is the entire stack trace. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850867/how-to-inspect-proguard-process-so-i-know-what-takes-so-long)

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 where is available proguard configuration file

Comment: @VinothKumar You should find a `proguard-rules.pro` file in your /app directory. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995401/android-studio-signed-apk-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea). I guess the answer there is useful

Comment: Thanks i fixed the issue

Comment: @VinothKumar You should post an answer for how you fixed the issue and mark it as the accepted answer